# ¿Como puedo cambiar de nuevo los botones de color con jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

estoy haciendo un ejercicio con Jquery el cual consiste en hacer unos botones que al hacerle click cambie el color de fondo y el texto de cada uno y cuando vuelva a apretar vuelva a su estado original, utilice el comando de Hasclass, pero no se que puede estar fallando,adjunto el código. Saludos y Gracias.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#rv").on("click",cambiar);



    function cambiar(){

        $("#rv").removeClass(".rojo").addClass(".verde").attr("value",)
    }
```

Comment: Hola, no se cargo el código

Answer (score 2):

Con `hasClass` averiguas si tiene cierta clase. Lo que puedes hacer es que si tiene esa clase, se la quitas (y si hace falta le pones otra). Si no tiene la clase, se la pones. Todo eso en un evento de `click`:

```js
var $botones = $('button');

$botones.click(evento => {
  var $elemento = $(evento.target);
   
  if ($elemento.hasClass('amarillo')) {
    $elemento.removeClass('amarillo');
    $elemento.html('Verde');
  }
  else {
    $elemento.addClass('amarillo');
    $elemento.html('Amarillo');
  }
});
```

```css
button {
  background-color: green;
}

.amarillo {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='1'>Verde</button>
<button id='2'>Verde</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

La manera mas simple seria:

```
function cambiar(){
   $("#rv").toggleClass("rojo verde").text($(this).attr('class'));
}
```